# Android: Record and listen audio

Tags: android, audio, media-player, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I try to implement a record and listen a audio from differents post, but I have a delay for 40 ms.

This is my code.

```
public class record {
    private AudioRecord recorder = null;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private int SAMPLERATE = 8000;
    private int CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    private int AUDIO_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    private int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLERATE, CHANNELS,
                    AUDIO_FORMAT);
    private Thread recordingThread = null;

    public void startRecording() {
            recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLERATE,
                            CHANNELS, AUDIO_FORMAT, bufferSize);

            recorder.startRecording();
            isRecording = true;

            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable()

            {
                    public void run() {
                            writeAudioData();
                    }

            });
            recordingThread.start();

    }

    public void stopRecording() {
            isRecording = false;
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
    }

    private void writeAudioData() {

            byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];

            int buff = 8000;
            int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(buff,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            Log.i("AUDIO", "BufferSize:" + minBufferSize);

            AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, buff,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,
                            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            at.play();

            while (isRecording) {
                    recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
                    at.write(data, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            at.stop();
            at.release();
    }
```

}

How can I reduce the delay?. I try reducing the buffer, but the problem still continue.

Comment: Include your code, don't post a link to an external site. Stackoverflow is aimed to help you and *future* users as well. Your link may be invalid in the future, and it's not searchable.

Comment: Ok, i just add my code. You have a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the measurement object and method, there could be tens of milliseconds delay or hundreds milliseconds delay in Android audio system.

If measuring the delay between the playing and the recording, 40ms delay is a normal value, actually I see 30~50ms delay value in my this test on Android 4.4.3:

> https://github.com/garyyu/AudioTracker-Test

Also, if you check your printed "minBufferSize" value, you will find this minimum buffer size is 40ms (on my Nexus7 2013). And there's frame delay when you play, we can't expect the immediate playing when calling "at.write()", I guess internally there's another buffer to store your "writing" data. And same in the recording side. So there're much more delay than 40ms if measuring from the playing start function call to the real sound output.
If need more suggestion, you need describe the detail about how do you measure your delay.

Comment: There have been extensive discussions about this, and I think your 40ms number might be quite a bit lower than reality, especially on older Android versions. I seem to remember that folks were seeing 150-250 ms delays in end-to-end processing. In order to make it helpful, you might want to revise your answer by providing at the very least which Android version the 40ms applies to.

Comment: I agree sometimes you can see hundreds ms delay. It's quite depending on what delay you're talking, as I mentioned in the answer above. If you measure a delay between playing and recording, maybe Giancarlo was doing this but we don't get his description for the detail, a tens of delay is possible. You can refer to my paste here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709775/audioflinger-181-recordthread-buffer-overflow). And if you're interesting on this, the source code for my that test is also available here: [link](https://github.com/garyyu/OpenSL-ES-Android-DelayTest).

Comment: Thanks @gary for the links. I think what @323go criticizes is that you argue for 40ms by referring to the result of `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize` which actually is only coarsely related with delay/latency. The main component is produced by `AudioRecord`/`AudioTrack` and `read()`/`write()`, respectively.